# Javascript prevent NaN while dividing

Tags: javascript, pi

I have been working on a PI calculation program using javascript.

```
     circumference
Pi = -------------
       diameter
```

When `r = the radius`, the circumference = 2πr, and the diameter = 2r.

This is what I have tried to do:

```
    var pi = Math.Pi,
    var r = 2
    ans = (2 * pi * r) / (2 * r);
    alert(ans);
```

Seems like it should work, right? But instead I get an alert message that says, "**NaN**."

Is there any way I can make a function like this:

```
function divide(numerator, denominator, decimal_places){
    //code
}
//and then:
divide(2πr, 2r, 30);//that would calculate Pi to 30 decimal places.
```

Does anyone know how I could make such a function using javascript? Thank you so much.

Comment: because `Math.Pi` is `undefined`. oops forgot to add its `Math.PI` not `Math.Pi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `PI`, not `Pi` - javascript is case-sensitive. + omit the second `var`:

```
var pi = Math.PI,
    r = 2
ans = (2 * pi * r) / (2 * r);
alert(ans);
```